# How can i stick my UITableViewCell at the end of the keyboard height?

Tags: swift, uitableview, keyboard-events

I have a dynamic cell that has a `UITextView` in the end if each cell. What i do is to move the UITableViewCell content Insets to a certain distance according to the keyboard height so it would not be hidden under the keyboard when the user writes down his comment.

What actually happens is that when the cell is at the bottom of the screen it scrolls to the exact location but when the cell is already above the keyboard height it remains in its place.

What i need is to scroll it down also when it is away up high on the screen so that the end of the cell is always stuck directly over the keyboard.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        feedTableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height - 35, 0)
        feedTableView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height - 35, 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `feedTableView.contentOffset` to scroll the view to a particular position.

Comment: @Jumhyn the issue is that i need first to know the space height between the keyboard and the end of the cell so i would calculate the offset.